# Delimiting contiguous regions with values above a certain threshold in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe of indices and values between 0 and 1, something like this:

```
 6  0.047033
 7  0.047650
 8  0.054067
 9  0.064767
10  0.073183
11  0.077950
```

I would like to retrieve tuples of **the start and end points of regions of more than 5 consecutive values that are all over a certain threshold (e.g. 0.5)**. So that I would have something like this:

```
 [(150, 185), (632, 680), (1500,1870)]
```

Where the first tuple is of a region that starts at index 150, has 35 values that are all above 0.5 in row, and ends on index 185 non-inclusive.

I started by filtering for only values above 0.5 like so

```
 df = df[df['values'] >= 0.5]
```

And now I have values like this:

```
632  0.545700
633  0.574983
634  0.572083
635  0.595500
636  0.632033
637  0.657617
638  0.643300
639  0.646283
```

I can't show my actual dataset, but the following one should be a good representation

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *

np.random.seed(seed=901212)

df = DataFrame(range(1,501), columns=['indices'])
df['values'] = np.random.rand(500)*.5 + .35
```

yielding:

```
 1  0.491233
 2  0.538596
 3  0.516740
 4  0.381134
 5  0.670157
 6  0.846366
 7  0.495554
 8  0.436044
 9  0.695597
10  0.826591
...
```

Where the region (2,4) has two values above 0.5. *However this would be too short.* On the other hand, the region (25,44) with 19 values above 0.5 in a row would be added to list.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can find the first and last element of each consecutive region by looking at the series and 1-row shifted values, and then filter the pairs which are adequately apart from each other:

```
# tag rows based on the threshold
df['tag'] = df['values'] > .5

# first row is a True preceded by a False
fst = df.index[df['tag'] & ~ df['tag'].shift(1).fillna(False)]

# last row is a True followed by a False
lst = df.index[df['tag'] & ~ df['tag'].shift(-1).fillna(False)]

# filter those which are adequately apart
pr = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(fst, lst) if j > i + 4]
```

so for example the first region would be:

```
>>> i, j = pr[0]
>>> df.loc[i:j]
    indices    values   tag
15       16  0.639992  True
16       17  0.593427  True
17       18  0.810888  True
18       19  0.596243  True
19       20  0.812684  True
20       21  0.617945  True
```

Comment: Nice solution. Would you expect this to remain fairly performant, even on larger datasets?

Comment: @Higany I guess the best answer would be to try it, and see how it would scale

Comment: @Higany these are all vectorized operations (except getting the actual indexers), so should be quite performant.

Answer (score 1):

I think this prints what you want. It is based heavily on [Joe Kington's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4495197/3751373) I guess it is appropriate to up-vote that.

```
import numpy as np

# from Joe Kington's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4495197/3751373
# with minor edits
def contiguous_regions(condition):
    """Finds contiguous True regions of the boolean array "condition". Returns
    a 2D array where the first column is the start index of the region and the
    second column is the end index."""

    # Find the indicies of changes in "condition"
    d = np.diff(condition,n=1, axis=0)
    idx, _ = d.nonzero() 

    # We need to start things after the change in "condition". Therefore, 
    # we'll shift the index by 1 to the right. -JK
    # LB this copy to increment is horrible but I get 
    # ValueError: output array is read-only without it 

    mutable_idx = np.array(idx)
    mutable_idx +=  1
    idx = mutable_idx

    if condition[0]:
        # If the start of condition is True prepend a 0
        idx = np.r_[0, idx]

    if condition[-1]:
        # If the end of condition is True, append the length of the array
        idx = np.r_[idx, condition.size] # Edit

    # Reshape the result into two columns
    idx.shape = (-1,2)
    return idx

def main():
    import pandas as pd
    RUN_LENGTH_THRESHOLD = 5
    VALUE_THRESHOLD = 0.5

    np.random.seed(seed=901212)
    data = np.random.rand(500)*.5 + .35

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['values'])

    match_bools =  df.values > VALUE_THRESHOLD 


    print('with boolian array')
    for start, stop in contiguous_regions(match_bools):
        if (stop - start > RUN_LENGTH_THRESHOLD):
            print (start, stop)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would be surprised if there were not more elegant ways

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer a predominantly pandas-based version if possible. A NumPy version may be preferable for performance reasons though.

Comment: Pandas is written with performance in mind. I would no be surprised if the solution from @behzad.nourisolution was as fast.  [IPython's %timeit magic](http://pynash.org/2013/03/06/timing-and-profiling.html) can be useful for quick profiling