# Python Pandas Timeseries How to find the largest sequence where the values is higher than a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

How do I find the largest sequence in a timeseries.
For example I have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
index      Value 
1-1-2012   10
1-2-2012   14
1-3-2012   15
1-4-2012   8
1-5-2012   7
1-6-2012   16
1-7-2012   17
1-8-2012   18
```

Now I want to get the longest sequence:
Here it would be the sequence from `1-6-2012` until `1-8-2012` with 3 entries.

Thanks
Anja

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit clunky but does the job. As you didn't specify the 'specific value' mentioned in the title, I choose 12.

```
import pandas as pd

time_indecies = pd.date_range(start='2012-01-01', end='2012-08-01', freq='MS')
data = [10, 14, 15, 8, 7, 16, 17, 18]
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': data, 't_indices': time_indecies })

threshold = 12
df['tag'] = df.vals > threshold

# make another DF to hold info about each region
regs_above_thresh = pd.DataFrame()

# first row of consecutive region is a True preceded by a False in tags
regs_above_thresh['start_idx']  = \
    df.index[df['tag'] & ~ df['tag'].shift(1).fillna(False)]

# last row of consecutive region is a False preceded by a True   
regs_above_thresh['end_idx']  = \
   df.index[df['tag'] & ~ df['tag'].shift(-1).fillna(False)] 

# how long is each region
regs_above_thresh['spans'] = \
    [(spam[0] - spam[1] + 1) for spam in \
    zip(regs_above_thresh['end_idx'], regs_above_thresh['start_idx'])]

# index of the region with the longest span      
max_idx = regs_above_thresh['spans'].argmax()

# we can get the start and end points of longest region from the original dataframe 
df.ix[regs_above_thresh.ix[max_idx][['start_idx', 'end_idx']].values]
```

The consecutive region cleverness is from behzad.nouri's [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24283319/3751373).

Comment: With the most recent version of pandas, (spam[0] - spam[1] + 1) needs to be ( (spam[0] - spam[1]).total_seconds() + 1