# Github action linkcheck not passing due to stackoverflow links

Tags: python, github, github-actions, documentation, broken-links

In our documentation, compiled through Sphinx, we have a few links to Stack Overflow answers (to acknowledge the good suggestions found there). We run a link check Action to verify that we don't have broken links, and today all Stack Overflow links started being reported broken, with errors like:

```
Warning, treated as error:
/home/runner/work/stingray/stingray/docs/api.rst:27:broken link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494404/find-large-number-of-consecutive-values-fulfilling-condition-in-a-numpy-array (403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494404/find-large-number-of-consecutive-values-fulfilling-condition-in-a-numpy-array)
(             api: line   27) linkcheck: exit 2 (63.54 seconds) /home/runner/work/stingray/stingray/docs> sphinx-build -W -b linkcheck .
```

But I verified by hand that these links are not broken. Is Stack Overflow limiting links somehow? Is there a way to put links to SO in our documentation?

Comment: I can confirm that I am also facing this exact same issue.

I'm using markdown-link-check, and the weird thing is that when I run markdown-link-check manually on my terminal, all tests pass but in the GitHub CI, the StackOverflow link gets flagged repeatedly.

Comment: It seems that the problem is solved, or better, that is not there anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I don't know what changed, but yeah, the SO links aren't getting flagged anymore.